# A class with 10 kids lines up for recess. Two of the kids in the class are named Lucy and Frank.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

A class with 10 kids lines up for recess. Two of the kids in the class are named Lucy and Frank. Assume that the order in which the kids line up is random (that is, all outcomes are equally likely). What is the probability that Lucy is first in line or Frank is last in line?

$$\frac{\binom{10}{9}}{2^{10}}+\frac{\binom{10}{9}}{2^{10}}=\frac{5}{2^8}$$

Can anyone verify this answer please..

Comment: Could you explain how you found the expression you proposed? This way, we will be able to fully assess the correctness of your solution.

Comment: Is this exclusive or (it must be one or the other), or can it be both? And yes, a bit of the work you did leading up to your solution may help.

Comment: @Henrik Why did you reject [Yuchen's suggested edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/1007331)?  MathJax gives the correct horizontal spacing around '+' and '='.  This [improves the readability](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22025/is-it-required-to-use-mathjax-for-simple-listings-of-numbers) of the post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The probability that Lucy is first is $\frac 1{10}$. 
The probability that Frank is last is $\frac 1{10}$. 
The probability that both happens is $\frac1{10}\cdot \frac 19$. So the probaility of "OR" is $\frac1{10}+\frac1{10}-\frac1{90}=\frac{17}{90}$

Comment: Can you please explain why did you multiply with $\frac{1}{9}$ and later subtracted from $\frac{1}{90}$

Comment: If you work out the problem by writing down all $6$ ways for a class of three kids to line up you will see why you should subtract that last term. If it's still not clear, write down all $24$ ways for a class of four kids. Much better than trying to learn which formula to use.

Answer (score 2):

- There are $10!$ arrangements altogether.
- There are $9!$ arrangements with Lucy first.
- There are $9!$ arrangements with Frank last.
- There are $8!$ arrangements with Lucy first **and** Frank last.
  So, all together
  $$\frac{9!+9!-8!}{10!}= \frac{8!}{10!}(2\cdot 9 - 1)=\frac{17}{90}$$

Comment: please tell me why to divide by $10!$

Comment: Each arrangement represents a possible outcome. All arrangements are equally likely. So, alltogether, there are $10!$ possible outcomes, as there are $10$ kids who line up.

Answer (score 1):

Each of the terms in your sum is $1/2^{10}$. You seem to think one is the probability that Lucy is first, the other the probability that Frank is last. But they are much too small for that.

Their sum is not $1/2^8$.

Moreover, you haven't thought through the problem. Solve it for a class with just two or three kids by listing all the possibilities. Then generalize.